# Googlesheet Regex : only capture first URL from multiple image URL

Tags: regex, url, google-sheets-query

Example input:

> (a
>   data-zoom-image="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/5f444a2891627135a18d90f22b51fc0/d/m/dm104-2.jpg"
>   ,
>   data-image="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/35f444a289162715a18d90f22b51fc0/d/m/dm104-2.jpg"
>   a data-zoom
>   image="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/70x70/35f444a2891627135a18d90f2b51fc0/d/m/dm104-2.jpg"
>   a
>   data-zoom-image="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/35f444a2891627135a18d9022b1fc0/m/i/mirror_disclaimer_web_16.jpg"
>   )

I want to capture only the first url after that part (< a data-zoom-image=")

> (https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/5f444a2891627135a18d90f22b51fc0/d/m/dm104-2.jpg)

How can I do that in googlesheet using regularexpression.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REGEXEXTRACT method like this

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A24, "data-zoom-image=""([^\""]*)")
```

## Explanantion -

`data-zoom-image=""` -- match for exact text `data-zoom-image="` (using `""` to represent `"`)
`([^\""]*)` -- first capturing group, this is the result that would be displayed
`[^\""]` -- any character that is not `"` (again using `""`)
`*`  -- match zero or more times

Comment: I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.Thank you so much.

Comment: You welcome. If it solve the issue please accept the answer so the question appears as answered.